# React-redux. Methods dumb component is not available from the container

Tags: react-redux

Strange effect in react-redux.
My "dumb" components have a method that returns the modified value.
Called getNewValues.
The container, when necessary, queries the components:

```
let jsn = '';
for ( let c in this.myRefs )
    if ( this.myRefs[c].getNewValues )
        jsn += this.myRefs[c].getNewValues();
```

Everything worked fine until I wrapped the "stupid" component in Сonnect.
Methods "dumb" component is not available from the container.
What to do?

Comment: could you provide the whole thing please?

Comment: My question is theoretical: how from the container to take the state "dumb" component?
I did: the container stores references to the components. Via a link you can call the method and get the state. Everything worked perfectly (without the react-redux). After connecting the react-redux methods of  component undefined. The debugger shows that the link points to an object Connect. Props correct. Methods do not exist

Comment: If I got it right, you are trying to call children methods (your dumb component) from the parent (your container). If so, I dont think this is the best wayto do it, consider passing down a method as prop to your component, so that the component calls this method when it has to, does that make sense?

Comment: All right. I need to know the state of the dumb components